# Avoid Refreshing function inside a component during state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component who update local state

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        number: 0
    }

    refreshState() {
        this.setState({number: this.state.number++})
    }


   render() {
       const key = '2018-12-13T10:00:00.000Z'
       return (
  <div>
        <CountDown
          until={getDurationLeft(key)}
          size={20}
          timeToShow={['H', 'M', 'S']}
        />
      <button onPress={() => this.refreshState()} />
   <div>
   )
}

getDurationLeft = key => {
    const date = new Date()
    return new Date(key).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000
}
```

The countdown component display time left between key and current date

But each time i push button, the function 'getDurationLeft' is recompute

When i press button fastly the time refreshment display the same seconds

See gif http://recordit.co/mHz7AHCNuT

During this video i am pressing button very fast

How to avoid to recompute getDurationLeft when state is refresh

Thanks

Comment: what's inside you countdown component?

Comment: Just a <div>{duration}</div>

Comment: There are many solutions to what you want to fix. I think the simplest would be to implement a 1-second debounce function around the button click callback. That way you can be somewhat confident you won't be recomputing faster than the timer.

Comment: I don't understand the question, since 'clicking the button very fast' suggest 'more than one click per same second'. If it's meant to be like a clock, a setInterval could trigger the state update every second. If it's mean to always update when clicked, it works as intended, since i'm missing the point of debouncing the update when the requirement is 'show the current difference when clicked'.

Comment: Can you show me an exemple ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it adding this

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return getDurationLeft(key) > 0
  }
```